# jboss-as-maven-plugin pom configuration

Tags: java, maven, plugins, jboss, pom.xml

I am using `jboss-as-maven-plugin` into the `pom.xml`. I can find online some documentation, but not about the configuration...

For example, I have this:

```java
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>7.8.Final</version>
    <configuration>
        <!--
             In produzione c'e' JBoss EAP 6.3 => JBoss AS 7.4.0.Final
             ma tale release non e' disponibile nei repo Maven
             quindi usiamo la versione piu' simile disponibile
          -->
        <version>7.4.0.Final-redhat-4</version>
        <jvmArgs>-Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
            -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000
            -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000
            -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=100
            -Djboss.server.config.dir=${project.build.testOutputDirectory}/configuration
            ${jacocoAgent}
        <!--    &lt;!&ndash;per eseguire il debug remoto rimuovere il commento dalla riga sottostante-->
        <!--    -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=33333,server=y,suspend=y-->
        </jvmArgs>
        <port>10099</port>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>start</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>start</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <startup-timeout>120</startup-timeout>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>avoid-console-logging</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>execute-commands</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <execute-commands>
                    <commands>
                        <command>/subsystem=logging/root-logger=ROOT:root-logger-unassign-handler(name="CONSOLE")</command>
                    </commands>
                </execute-commands>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>deploy</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>stop</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>undeploy</goal><!-- Per eseguire "mvn verify" e non solo "mvn clean verify" -->
                <goal>shutdown</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Where I can find the meaning and purpose of all tags, and of all the tags of the plugin I haven't used in this example?

Comment: I'd suggest using the [`wildfly-maven-plugin`](https://docs.wildfly.org/wildfly-maven-plugin). It works with EAP 7 and really EAP 6 if you tweak the management port. Version 3.0.2 supports Java 8. 4+ requires Java 11.

Comment: how can i tweak management port? And the question is also for the plugin you mentioned

Comment: Which goal are you using? It should be <port> though. For EAP 6 the default is 9999. For EAP 7 the default is 9990. The wildfly-maven-plugin uses 9990 by default.